# Object at URL of type is invalid because a required property of type 'string' was not provided

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

Lately, when I use open graph to post an update to facebook I having this issue

> "Object at URL 'http://gallery.mobile9.com/f/3536031/' of type 'social-mobilenine:file' is invalid because a required property 'social-mobilenine:file' of type 'string' was not provided."

I checked my meta in the url and it is

```
<meta content="social-mobilenine:file" property="og:type">
```

Any idea?

I also tested using facebook developer open graph http version. where the return is like such

```
    {
      "error": {
      "type": "Exception", 
      "message": "Object at URL 'http://gallery.mobile9.com/f/3542967/?ref=5756' of type 'social-mobilenine:file' is invalid because a required property 'social-mobilenine:file' of type 'string' was not provided.", 
      "code": 1611008
    }}
```